# My site identity bar is way too big. It is also stationary when I scroll down - I don't want that. How doI change it?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

[Where do I edit the white space? Or in other words, where can I add more spacing/remove white spacing? It seems way too big for the website when I scroll down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR4t1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your theme probably has some CSS code that styles that part of the theme. It is usually in the file style.css, however it depends on the theme.

If there are no options in the theme's panel, there are two options (both require CSS code):
You can add your CSS rules through the administrator panel in Appearance > Edit CSS. 
Or you can write a child theme and add some css rules that define the spacing in that part.